# Exception with new WordDocument() com.independentsoft

Tags: java, independentsoft

I have existing working project on java. I need to change template ".docx" document. When I'm trying to create a new WordDocument with another ".docx" document, I get an exception. What can be wrong?
Sorry for my english.

There is a my code:

```
`WordDocument document = new WordDocument(templatesDirectory + "order.docx");`
```

There is a stacktrace:

```
`java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "11340.0"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at com.independentsoft.office.word.tables.Width.a(Unknown Source)
at com.independentsoft.office.word.tables.Width.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.independentsoft.office.word.tables.TableProperties.a(Unknown Source)
at com.independentsoft.office.word.tables.TableProperties.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.independentsoft.office.word.tables.Table.a(Unknown Source)
at com.independentsoft.office.word.tables.Table.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.independentsoft.office.word.Body.a(Unknown Source)
at com.independentsoft.office.word.Body.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.independentsoft.office.word.WordDocument.a(Unknown Source)
at com.independentsoft.office.word.WordDocument.openImplementation(Unknown Source)
at com.independentsoft.office.word.WordDocument.open(Unknown Source)
at com.independentsoft.office.word.WordDocument.open(Unknown Source)
at com.independentsoft.office.word.WordDocument.<init>(Unknown Source)`
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved! The problem was in a file, it was saved with google docs. Now I resave it with MSOffice, and so code works!

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the message you get in the Exception: it says

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "11340.0"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
```

Somewhere in your code you are trying to generate an `Integer` from a `String` that cannot be *converted* to an `Integer`.
In your case: `11340.0`: although the mathematical value is an integer value, Java understands that it is a `Float` or a `Double` because of the ending `.0` and raises an exception.

Try to find where that convertion occurs from and see if you can catch / manage the exception.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But there is problem not in my code, I think. This exception was thrown when I change template .docx file. May be problem in this file(may be table width), but I don't know, where exactly and what should i do to fix it:    
 "at com.independentsoft.office.word.tables.Width.a(Unknown Source)"